# How do I remove a user from an AutoForward on a public folder in Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

I have a mail-enabled Public Folder in Exchange 2007 that forwards mail to three specific users. I need to remove one of those users, but I can't seem to locate where I would do that. Any suggestions? Commandlets to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the properties of the Public Folder itself using Outlook (assuming you have the proper client rights to the PF).

Typically it is in the Folder Assistant or it could be setup there to be "Moderated" under the Administration tab.

Or it might be forwarded to an email address associated with a distribution group possibly under the same Folder Assistant view or in Exchange itself.  You can see if there are any forwarded addresses configured directly on the Public Folder through PowerShell:

```
get-mailpublicfolder -identity "nameofPF" | fl
```

look for a ForwardingAddress in the output...if it is there you can modify it in the Public Folder mgmt tool inside EMC.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it took me so long to get back. It was in Folder Assistant in Outlook.